# Large MYSQL dump With Bad Encoding Chars

Tags: mysql, xml, regex, perl

I have written perl code to parse xml from a mysqldump. The issue is the database stores data in latin-1 (its an old system..) . Users are pasting UTF-8 data into the system which makes its way out in the mysql xml dump. (The upstream system is outside of my control, so I can not remove the bad data, which is clearly the best way to go..)

Right now I am going through the files and clearing out the bad encoding characters with regex so that my xml parser will not die when it hits those characters.

```
sub  correctBadEncoding
{
   my ( $path2File,$nameOfFile) = @_;
   my $file2Convert ;
   my $tempFile2Convert;
   open($file2Convert ,'<:raw' ,$path2File. $nameOfFile)|| die("Unable to read ".$path2File. $nameOfFile."\n"); 
   open($tempFile2Convert ,'>:encoding(UTF-8)' ,$path2File."tmp_".$nameOfFile)|| die("Unable to read temp path for ".$path2File. $nameOfFile."\n"); 
   while (my $line = <$file2Convert>) 
   { 
      $line =~ s/[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]//gox;#strips just about everything out
      #thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016910/how-can-i-strip-invalid-xml-characters-from-strings-in-perl
      my $oc2Write = Encode::encode("UTF-8", $line); 
      print $tempFile2Convert $oc2Write; 
   } 
   close($file2Convert);
   close($tempFile2Convert);
   unlink($path2File. $nameOfFile) or print "Failed to remove old file(for encoding)!";
   move($path2File."tmp_".$nameOfFile, $path2File. $nameOfFile) or print "Failed to move temp to true file(for encoding)!";
   return 1;

}
```

The problem is it takes about 1 to 2.5 hours to go through each line of the files and remove the bad characters. If I take files that have been cleaned and just run the xml parsing process it takes about 15-30 minutes to process the data and do what I need to with it(this includes the xml parsing).   Is there anything I can do to speed up removing the invalid characters that would be faster then the current method ?

***EDIT***
Here is a hex example of the bad string

3c6669656c64206e616d653d226e6f7465223e4e6f7420436f6d706c657465643a20204920676f74204f535046207475726e656420757020627574204920636f756c646ee2742067657420697420646f776e6772616465642e20205468652066696c6573206f6e207468652066747020666f6c64657220636f756c646ee274206265206f70656e65642062792074686520353020666f7220736f6d6520726561736f6e2e2020200d0a0d0a20413a736f6d65686f73742d3530232066696c6520636f7079206674703a2f2f6361743a636174403132372e302e302e312f686f6d652f646e6f632f526f75746572732f35302f626f6f742e6c6472206366333a35302d4f532d3130302e312e426f6f742e6c6472200d0a4d494e4f523a20434c492043616e6e6f74206f70656e20696e7075742066696c65206674703a2f2f6361743a636174403132372e302e302e312f686f6d652f6361742f526f75746572732f35302f626f6f742e6c64722e0d0a66696c6520636f7079206674703a2f2f6361743a636174403132372e302e302e312f526f75746572732f35302f626f6f742e6c6472206366333a35302d4f532d3130302e312e426f6f742e6c64723c2f6669656c643e

(feel free to use a converter...http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx, or look a the comments below to see the text in its normal output, but its displays may change by browser..)

**Edit**
There are several files with different lengths sizes , the largest is 1.4G, 38,695,571 lines

Comment: What happens if you specify the character set when you run `mysqldump`? e.g. `mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1 ...`

Comment: Tried that and it does not remove the bad "characters"..its mysql 5.1 (mysqldump 10)

Comment: Could you show a section of XML containing the bad data? I'm not able to generate a dump containing illegal XML characters, even when I write to a `latin1` table using a `utf8` connection, among other things. Garbled data, yes, illegal characters, no. (MySQL 5.1.67, `mysqldump` 10.13)

Comment: <field name="note">Not Completed:  I got OSPF turned up but I couldnât get it downgraded.  The files on the ftp folder couldnât be opened by the 50 for some reason.   

 A:somehost-50# file copy ftp://cat:cat@127.0.0.1/home/dnoc/Routers/50/boot.ldr cf3:50-OS-100.1.Boot.ldr 
MINOR: CLI Cannot open input file ftp://cat:cat@127.0.0.1/home/cat/Routers/50/boot.ldr.
file copy ftp://cat:cat@127.0.0.1/Routers/50/boot.ldr cf3:50-OS-100.1.Boot.ldr</field>

Comment: `â` is a bad representation (or storage) of the `'` character in your DB. can you confirm by doing HEX(field) in your MySQL to see whether the data IS stored correctly in your DB and just not dumped correctly?

Comment: The issue is the db is in latin but someone pasted in utf so ' gets moved to â because of it being utf version of ' and not the latin version(i.e utf has 2 ', there are several chars like this..) .. â is how its stored...I don't control the upstream system..and long term the hope is to change the storage format, just not for a few years..
hence the question of how to solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using perl 5.14 or later, you can take advantage of the fact that perl operates on characters instead of bytes, and use the faster `tr///` command:

```
$line =~ tr/\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}//cd ;
```

If that's still not fast enough, I would write a small C program to read in the first file and trim out the characters.